# How do you perform p4 sync on two files in the same string

Tags: perforce, p4v

Here is my command but i'm only syncing one file. Can I seperate them by comma or is there a better way

```
syncCommand = ["p4", "-c", workspace_name, "sync",  "//depot/proj1/...File1.cfg "]
```

For example :

```
def pullfile(): 
syncCommand = ["p4", "-c", workspace_name, "sync",  "//depot/proj1/...File1.cfg, File2.cfg "]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sync command accepts multiple file arguments:

```
def pullfile(): syncCommand = ["p4", "-c", workspace_name, "sync", "//depot/proj1/...File1.cfg", "//depot/proj1/...File2.cfg"]
```